# Ubuntu Software doesn't open even after the fix release

Tags: 16.04, software-center, gnome-software

I know there are couple of questions for this asked here but all of them lead me to this [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573052). The page says the problem is fixed and the fix is released. However, I still see the issue.

I have upgraded my system literally few mins ago and when running `gnome-software` from terminal, I see the exact same error.

```
Gs-WARNING **: failed to open plugin /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: /usr/lib/gs-plugins-9/libgs_plugin_xdg_app_reviews.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu Software won't launch but has a process running.

#### What have I tried?

- Restarting.
- Installing upgrades and restarting.
- Re-installing gnome-software
- Removing and installing gnome-software.

None of them seem to fix the problem and it's absolutely annoying. Is there something that I can do to better understand the problem and fix it?

Comment: Are you using the GNOME3 Staging PPA for xenial?

Comment: The developers have said that the plugin error you see is harmless and you can ignore it. The problem is something else.

Comment: So where can i get more info/log about gnome-software in the system? and I am not sure which PPA. I got it from the xenial image i downloaded from ubuntu's website. Never had to add explicit PPA for gnome-software.

Comment: Don't worry about PPAs. If you had used a PPA, it might have had other affects on your computer but that's apparently not the case here.